# Remove a list from a list of lists in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe, with a list column, that contains a list of lists.
In some specific cases, this list contains one unique list, with contains only empty strings.

```
+--+---------------+
|id|list           |
+--+---------------+
|1 |[[1, a],[2, b]]|
|2 |[[,]]          |
```

And I would like to filter out this list, so that I have the following:

```
+--+---------------+--------------+
|id|list           |result        |
+--+---------------+--------------+
|1 |[[1, a],[2, b]]|[[1, a],[2, b]|
|2 |[[,]]          |[]            |
```

I have tried the following:

```py
data_frame.withColumn("result", array_remove("list", ["",""]))
```

but I have the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_remove. Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [, ]
```

Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky here - I think using a raw Spark SQL query will be appropriate:

```
df2 = data_frame.withColumn('result', F.expr("array_remove(list, array('',''))"))

df2.show()
+---+----------------+----------------+
| id|            list|          result|
+---+----------------+----------------+
|  1|[[1, a], [2, b]]|[[1, a], [2, b]]|
|  2|          [[, ]]|              []|
+---+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: I just tried, it seems to almost work!
I tried to simplify, but it appears my list is not composed of arrays, but of structs, and I have a type mismatch:

`AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'array_remove("list", array('', ''))' due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_remove should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<struct<id:int,body:string>>, array<string>]`

Is it possible to replace `array('','')` with a harcoded instance of this struct?